# how to duplicate cin

Tags: c++, cin

I tried to do

```
auto cin2 = cin;
int a;
cin2 >> a;
```

But the compiler only gives me not understandable errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:47: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:53: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Hang on a sec... Why do you want to "duplicate" `std::cin`?

Comment: "What is the correct way to do this?" not doing it.

Comment: "But the compiler only gives me not understandable errors": it is basicly saying that `ios_base` copy constructor is private and you cant copy it.

Comment: `C++` streams are not copyable. But what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to implement my own istream_iterator class and it gives me the same error as this. Should I do everything as reference?

Comment: I think it would be normal for an iterator to hold a reference (or a pointer) to the (pseudo)container it iterates over.

Comment: If you really want to make a duplicate `cin`, you're probably going to need to learn your compiler's heavy wizardry, and basically find how your compiler defines `std::cin`.  For example, with `std::cout`: Some versions of Visual Studio use `#define _cpp_stdout (&(__iob_func())[1])`, then create a `std::filebuf` with it, and use that to make `std::cout`.  These versions also have `#define _cpp_stdin  (&(__iob_func())[0])` and `#define _cpp_stderr (&(__iob_func())[2])`, which are used in the same way, to create `std::cin` and `std::cerr`, respectively.

Comment: I would recommend _not_ actually doing this, though, unless possibly if you want to create a `char16_t` or `char32_t` version, _**AND**_ know that all platforms you intend to work with can support UTF-16 or UTF-32 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard class `std::istream` is not copyable.  You can declare a reference to `std::cin` for example the following way

```
decltype(auto) cin2 = ( std::cin );
int a;
cin2 >> a;
```

Or you can write

```
auto &cin2 = std::cin;
```

To implement an istream iterator you can use a reference or pointer to the stream.

Comment: Wouldn't `auto& cin2 = cin;` be more readable and less error prone?

Comment: @Rakete1111 As usual there are several ways to do a task.:)

Comment: it is easy to forget the parens when assigning when using `decltype(auto)` because of its weird type deducing, that's why I was wondering why you used that way :) But oh well

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have updated my post according to your remark. Thanks.